# "Bad state: Tried to read the state of an uninitialized provider" with riverpod while listening to futureprovider

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation

I have this generated notifier that should rebuild when the data changes without loosing its reference to a previously selected object on rebuild.

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive:true)
Future<List<MyModel>> modelList (ModelListRef ref) {
    return ref.watch(modelRepositoryProvider).getModels();
}

@Riverpod(keepAlive:true)
class MyController extends _$MyController {
  
  @override
  MyModel? build() {
    return ref.watch(modelListProvider).maybeWhen(
      //Accessing this state throws the error                             ↓
      data: (models) => models.singleWhereOrNull((model) => model.id == state?.id),
      orElse: () => null,
    );
  }
  
  @override 
  set state (MyModel value){
    state = value;
   }
}
```

I am calling

```dart
  ref.invalidate(modelListProvider);
```

after changing data to trigger a rebuild but when I am reading the notifiers state again, I am getting an error:

`StateError (Bad state: Tried to read the state of an uninitialized provider)`

and the stacktrace leads me to the state of the notifier. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for now:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive:true)
class MyController extends _$MyController {
  
  @override
  MyModel? build() {
   state = null;
   ref.listen(
     modelListProvider,
     (previous, next) {
       next.maybeWhen(
         data: (models) {
           state = models.firstWhereOrNull((model) => model.id == state?.id);
         },
         orElse: (){
           state = null;
         },
       );
     },
     fireImmediately: true,
   );
   return state;
  }
  
  @override 
  set state (MyModel value){
    state = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should initialize the state with an empty object of MyModel type, not null or use generic types if your MyModel is compatible. For instance, if it is a list, just use state=[]. Otherwise, create an empty constructor in your model and use it like this state=MyModel.empty()